# Python List parsing (incude int, str)

Tags: python, list, parsing

I have a list with (int, str)
`x = ['2', '3/4', '+', '4', '3/5']`
I have to parse int (here its `2`and `4`). After I should parse `'3/4'` and then `'+'`

Can you help me find a way how can I parse int from list like that?
I tried "try, except", but it didn't work.
I can't use index, because in another list may be like
`x = ['3/4', '+', '1', '7/10']`

Comment: post the `try-except` you tried. It is also not clear what you want to do with the converted values; can you please specify that too? What is your end-goal?

Comment: `for i in x:
 if isinstance(i, int):
  g.append(i)`  
End of goal is  sum min, fractions :)

Comment: Edit the question and add your code there itself. Plus, you will need to add more than the line above.

Comment: There are no `int`s in that list: all its items are strings. Some of those strings may be converted to `int`.

Comment: a) put the comment in the question. b) of course it didn't work because `'4'` is a `str` instance.

Comment: `[int(val) for val in x if all(y.isdigit() for y in val)]` would get you a list containing the integers from your input list, but might not be suitable if you want to apply operations to the other entries.

Comment: It doesn't look like you tried too hard. http://ideone.com/oMz81i

Comment: I've  just never convert something with different vars included. 
@erip thank for func :) Thanks all :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the way to go:

```
x = ['2', '3/4', '+', '4', '3/5']
g = []
for i in x:
    try:
        g.append(int(i))
    except ValueError:
        pass
print(g)  # [2, 4]
```

What you tried is not a `try-except` block. It is an `if` statement which failed because `'4'` is not an `int` instance (`4` is, notice the quotes); it is a string.

There are of course other ways to do it too as mentioned in the comments. I only went for the `try-except` because you mentioned it in your comments.